# How to make dynamic tabs with Material-ui and GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, material-ui, react-apollo

I'm trying to make dynamic tabs in Material-ui.
My business domain is conferences. A conference runs over X days and every day there's a number of sessions being hosted.

I need some way to show these sessions in tabs using Material-ui. Since the number of days a conference is running is not fixed i need the number of tabs to vary. Plus on every tab I want to show the sessions for the day.

I'm using GraphQL, Apollo, React and Material-Ui.

I have the following GraphQL schema defined:

```
    export default `

   scalar Date

   enum SortDirection {
    ASCENDING
    DESCENDING
}

enum SortableSessionField {
    start_date
} 



  type Conference {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    address: String!
    start_date: String
    end_date: String
    sessions: [Session]
  }

  type Paper{
    id: ID!
    title: String!
  }

  type Session {
     conference_session_id: ID!
     session_title: String
     session_no: String
     chair_name: String
     discussant_1_name: String
     discussant_2_name: String
     room_description:String
     start_date: String
     start_time: String
     end_time: String
     papers: [Paper]
  }


type Query {
    conferences: [Conference!]!
    sessions(conferenceId: ID!, day: String!
             sort: SortDirection = DESCENDING
             sortBy: SortableSessionField = start_date): [Session]
    conference(id: ID!): Conference 
    session(id: ID!): Session
  }  


`;
```

The interesting function here is:

```
sessions(conferenceId: ID!, day: String!
                 sort: SortDirection = DESCENDING
                 sortBy: SortableSessionField = start_date): [Session]
```

Which given a conferenceid and a date returns all the sessions for the conference on that day. Testing in Graphql playground it returns the correct data.

I have the following basic React page:

```
import React from 'react'
import FullWidthTabs from '../components/Sessions'


class SessionsPage extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
              <FullWidthTabs days={['2018-06-11', '2018-06-12', '2018-06-13']}/>
          </div>

        );
    }
}
export default (SessionsPage);
```

what it does is basically just sending three dates to the FullWidthTabs page i just stole directly from Material-UI and modified to suit my needs:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import SessionTab from '../components/SessionTab'


        function TabContainer( { children }) {
            return (
                    <Typography component="div" style={{padding: 8 * 3}}>
                        {children}
                    </Typography>
                    );
        }

        TabContainer.propTypes = {
            children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
            dir: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        };

        const styles = theme => ({
                root: {
                    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
                    width: 500,
                },
            });

        class FullWidthTabs extends React.Component {
            state = {
                value: 0,
            };

            handleChange = (event, value) => {
                this.setState({value});
            }
            ;
                    handleChangeIndex = index => {
                        this.setState({value: index});
                    }
            ;
        render() {


                const tabs = this.props.days.map((day) => {
                    return (<Tab key={day.gridIndex} label={day} />)
                });
                const content = this.props.days.map((day) => {
                    return (<TabContainer><SessionTab conferenceId = "57" day={day}/></TabContainer>)
                });

                const {classes, theme} = this.props;

                return (
                        <div className={classes.root}>
                            <AppBar position="static" color="default">
                                <Tabs
                                    value={this.state.value}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    indicatorColor="primary"
                                    textColor="primary"
                                    variant="fullWidth"
                                    >
                                    { tabs }
                                </Tabs>
                            </AppBar>
                            <SwipeableViews
                                axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
                                index={this.state.value}
                                onChangeIndex={this.handleChangeIndex}
                                >
                                { content }
                            </SwipeableViews>
                        </div>
                        );
            }
        }

        FullWidthTabs.propTypes = {
            classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            theme: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        };

        export default withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(FullWidthTabs);
```

This component receives (in this case) three dates from the HOC and should initalize the three tabs and put some session info on each tab.

The component to show the session data is the SessionTab:

```
import React from 'react'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import { Query } from 'react-apollo'
import ConferenceCard from '../components/ConferenceCard';

const SESSIONS_QUERY = gql`
 query sessions($id: ID!, $day: String!){
    sessions(conferenceId: $id, day: $day)
      {conference_session_id
       session_title
       start_date
       start_time
       end_time
     }
  }
`

class SessionsTab extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props);
    }

    render() {
        let id = this.props.conferenceId;
        let day = this.props.day;
        console.log("SessionTab " + id + "  " + day);
        return (
                <Query query={SESSIONS_QUERY} variables={{id, day}}>
                    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                        if (loading)
                                return <div>Fetching</div>
                            if (error)
                                return <div>Error</div>
                            const sessionsToRender = data.sessions
                        return (
                           <div>
                              {sessionsToRender.map(session => <div> {session.conference_session_id} </div>)}
                           </div>
                        )
                    }}
                </Query>
                )
    }
}

export default (SessionsTab);
```

The sessionTab receives a conferenceId and a Data and finds all the sessions for the day. Testing in GraphQL playground it works.

Each SessionTab is intialized in the FullWidthTab like this:

```
 const content = this.props.days.map((day) => {
                    return (<TabContainer><SessionTab conferenceId = "57" day={day}/></TabContainer>)
                });
```

where the days props contain the dates passed from the sessionpage.

But it does not seem to work.

My questions are:

1) is this the right way to do things?
2) when run tab1 shows data while tab2 and tab3 shows error.

I don't know what it wrong but it looks like the SessionTab are not correctly intialized except for the first one.

Kim